# Data gets corrupted during transmission over the serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, communication

I am developing a program to communicate with an old system. I use System.IO.Ports.SerialPort for this. The problem is when I send a longer message, the message bevome corrupt. I use a line listener and get the following results

What I sending

```
aa 01 00 00 12 03 06 18 02 c1 94 02 c1 94 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1e fd
```

What I get

```
c2 aa 01 00 00 12 03 06 18 02 c3 81 c2 94 02 c3 81 c2 94 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1e c3 bd
```

The code I'm using is

```
_comPort.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
_comPort.PortName = PortName;  //Com1
_comPort.BaudRate = BaudRate;  //9600
_comPort.StopBits = StopBits;  //1
_comPort.DataBits = DataBits;  //8
_comPort.Parity   = Parity;    //None
_comPort.Open();

_comPort.Write(messageStr);
```

Why is data corrupted and how do I fix this?

Comment: Don't store binary data in string.  SerialPort.Write() does *not* encode in ascii when you pass a byte[], no encoding is necessary for bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `messageStr` is a string, and you're seeing encoding issues. You've explicitly specified the UTF-8 encoding, so that's what you're getting - but I *suspect* it's not what you really want.

You've shown *binary* data, so I assume you actually want to send exactly that binary data - in which case you should use the [`Write(byte[], int, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551.aspx) overload.

If you *really* want to write text data, you probably just need to pick the right encoding - but you'll need to give us more information for us to help you make the right choice.

Comment: Yes, it is binary data that I want to send. The problem is that both  Write(byte[], int, int) and Write(string) as default use ASCIIEncoding to encode characters, and then it can not handle characters larger than 127 (0x7F). And I have several bits that are bigger than that. That's why I changed Encoding. What Encoding should I have instead?

Comment: @magol If that is true, you may need to use base-64 (Convert.ToBase64String); however, I would expect Write(byte[], ...) to write binary

Comment: As shown in the manual for the Write (byte [], int, int), do I need Encoding. But I'll try.

Comment: @magol: These are *bytes*, not characters. I realize the remarks section of `Write` talks about encodings, but I don't think it really should. Have you tried using `Write(byte[]...)` already? It would be really weird if that applied any encoding at all. (I think it's a mistake that that's even mentioned on the page.) Conceptually there are no characters here, just bytes, so the encoding shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: You are right. Write(byte[], int, int) does not care about Encoding. Thank you very much for your help :-)